# How to merge a literal table into an existing table in snowflake, using SQL

Tags: python, merge, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to merge data into an existing table in my database. The data I want to merge is not in an existing table though, so I'd like to provide it to my database as a table literal in my SQL query. Below is the code that I've currently got - and it keeps erroring with a message:

`SQL compilation error: error line 8 at position 39 invalid identifier 'VALS.COL2'`

```
merge into existing_table
    using 
        (select col1, col2, parse_json(col3) from
            values 
            ('2021-08-03 17:38:53.977484+00:00', '34o234j3', $${"data":"here's some data","data2":"Here's some more data"}$$), 
            ('2021-08-02 08:38:55', '1934802h32', $${"data":"here's some dataX","data2":"Here's some more dataY"}$$)
            as vals(col1, col2, col3))
    on existing_table.sales_order_id = vals.col2
when matched then 
    update set 
        existing_table.timestamp_utc = vals.colOne, existing_table.JSON = vals.colThree
when not matched then
    insert (timestamp_utc, sales_order_id, JSON)
    values (vals.colOne, vals.colTwo, vals.colThree);
```

Note I am using the Snowflake application to hold data - the snowflake application is what allows for the parse_json() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to missing table alias as already corrected in the previous answer (using src as the alias), there are a few more errors/typos:

- parse_json(col3) needs an alias, added as col3
- inconsistent column naming, in the source query columns are named col1, col2, col3 but in the join conditions columns are referred as colOne, colTwo, colThree

Here is the corrected query that runs without errors

```
merge into existing_table
    using 
        (select col1, col2, parse_json(col3) as col3 from
            values 
            ('2021-08-03 17:38:53.977484+00:00', '34o234j3', $${"data":"here's some data","data2":"Here's some more data"}$$), 
            ('2021-08-02 08:38:55', '1934802h32', $${"data":"here's some dataX","data2":"Here's some more dataY"}$$)
            as vals(col1, col2, col3)) src
    on existing_table.sales_order_id = src.col2
when matched then 
    update set 
        existing_table.timestamp_utc = src.col1, existing_table.JSON = src.col3
when not matched then
    insert (timestamp_utc, sales_order_id, JSON)
    values (src.col1, src.col2, src.col3);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This, combined with the first answer, got me where I need to go. The typos with the col1 vs colOne and the alias on col3 were definitely part of the problem. This solution you provided worked great.

Answer (score 0):

I think the alias for the table of values is inside the sub-select, which then needs an alias.  I haven't tested this and it doesn't format well as a comment, so if it doesn't work, I'll delete this answer:

```
merge into existing_table
    using 
        (select col1, col2, parse_json(col3) from
            values 
            ('2021-08-03 17:38:53.977484+00:00', '34o234j3', $${"data":"here's some data","data2":"Here's some more data"}$$), 
            ('2021-08-02 08:38:55', '1934802h32', $${"data":"here's some dataX","data2":"Here's some more dataY"}$$)
            as vals(col1, col2, col3)) src
    on existing_table.sales_order_id = src.col2
when matched then 
    update set 
        existing_table.timestamp_utc = src.colOne, existing_table.JSON = src.colThree
when not matched then
    insert (timestamp_utc, sales_order_id, JSON)
    values (src.colOne, src.colTwo, src.colThree);
```